# Registration and validation form with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a problem with a registration form on angularjs, I want to controle the form before submit and how can i save user data in text file or json (any solution for saving data), I did not manage to do it.
For more information, I am working on a project : Interface for ReafctorErl public server - javascript (angular based).

registration.html :

```html
<div class="register">
  <div class="box">
 <h4> Sign Up</h4>
 <p> Enter your personal details below: </p>
 </br>
    <form role="frmRegister" name="frmRegister" ng-submit="register()" >
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" ng-model="credentials.fullname"/>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="organisation :" placeholder="Organisation" ng-model="credentials.organisation"  />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="address :" placeholder="Address" ng-model="credentials.address" />
      </div>

      <p> Enter your account details below: </p>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="credentials.email"  />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username" ng-model="credentials.username" />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group" >
        <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="credentials.password"  />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group" >
        <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password_again" placeholder="Password again" ng-model="credentials.password_again"  />
      </div>

      <div class="form-actions">
       <a href="#/login"  class="btn btn-link">Back</a>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return verif();">Submit</button>
      </div>
      </br>
   </form>

</div>
</div>
<script language="javascript">
function verif(){

 if (document.getElementById('password').value != document.getElementById('password_again').value) {
     document.getElementById('password_again').setCustomValidity('Passwords must match.');
 } 
 else {
      document.getElementById('password_again').setCustomValidity('');
 }
   
}
</script>
```

the controller file :

```js
'use strict';

function RegisterCtrl($scope, reg) {
 var credentials = {
  fullname: "",
        organisation: "",
        address: "",
        email: "",
        username: "",
  password: "",
        password_again: ""
 };
    $scope.credentials = credentials;
    $scope.restricted = window.restrictedMode;
 $scope.register = function() {
        
        if( $scope.frmRegister.fullname.length<1 ) {
            alert("Full Name required!");
            return false;
        }

        if( $scope.credentials.organisation.length<1 ) {
            alert("Organisation required!");
            return false;
        }

        if( $scope.credentials.address.length<1 ) {
            alert("Address required!");
            return false;
        }

        if( $scope.credentials.email.length<1 ) {
            alert("Email required!");
            return false;
        }

        if( $scope.credentials.username.length<1 ) {
            alert("Username required!");
            return false;
        }
  
  if( $scope.credentials.password.length<3 ) {
            alert("Password required!");
            return false;
        }

        if( $scope.credentials.password_again.length<3 ) {
            alert("Password again required!");
            return false;
        }
 reg.register($scope.credentials.fullname, $scope.credentials.organisation, $scope.credentials.address,
     $scope.credentials.email, $scope.credentials.username, $scope.credentials.password, $scope.credentials.password_again, true);
 };
}
```

Service file is :

```js
'use strict';

/*just trying todo something here */


angular.module('referl.services').service('reg', function($q, $http, $location, $rootScope, $window) {

 var reg = {

  register: function(fullname, organisation, address, email, username, password, password_again, navigateOnSuccess) {
   var parameters = {
    fullname: fullname,
    organisation: organisation,
    address: address,
    email: email,
    username: username,
    password: password,
    password_again: password_again

   };
   $http.get("api/register", {params: parameters}).success(function(response) {
                    if(response.error) {
                        alert(response.error);
                    } else {
                       alert("Success");
                    }
    });
   
  }




 };
 $rootScope.reg = reg;
 return reg;
});
```

Any help please ??
Thank you!

Comment: What is the direct relevance to Erlang tag?

Answer (score 0):

Better to follow https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms for html page that will reduce your angular controller code. and you can focus on service validation

Follow **Binding to form and control state** section of above link how to validate form.

Answer (score 0):

To your input text's u can use: ng-pattern and attribute required

```
<form name="exampleForm" class="form-horizontal">
 <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" ng-model="credentials.fullname" ng-pattern="INSERT PATTERN" required/>
  </div>
</form>
```

to find patterns you can see here:

[HTML5 pattern](http://www.html5pattern.com/)

and for valite the whole form

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="myFunction()" ng-disabled="exampleForm.$invalid">Button</button>
```